# Jquery getting ul depending a match in the child text in an anchor inside with variable value

Tags: jquery

I have the following javascript variable:

```
<script>
   var theme="Videocameras";
</script>
```

And the following html code:

```
<div>    
     <span>Tecnology</span>
     <ul id="menu">
         <li>
            <a href="#">Multimedia</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Videocameras</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Cameras</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">MP3 and MP4</a>
                </li>                  
            </ul> 
        </li> 
            <li>
            <a href="#">Telephony</a>
            <ul>              
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mobile Phones</a>
                </li>

            </ul> 
        </li> 
     </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to get a unique ul that has inside an href with text that matches to the value of the variable.

Could you give me a hand?
Best Regards.

Comment: In your example the `href` is just `#`, do you mean where the text matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`:contains`**](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [**`.closest()`**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Try this

```
 $("a:contains(" + theme + ")").closest("ul");
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zU7bU/)

Comment: Just have to be careful with this because `:contains(Cameras)` would match both `Video Cameras` and `Cameras`.  The OP incorrectly has the two as a single word in his code (*Videocameras*), so in that state it wouldn't be a problem.  If another developer comes along and cleans up his English, however, it could break :-)

Answer (score 1):

[@rahul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277654/jquery-getting-ul-depending-a-match-in-the-child-text-in-an-anchor-inside-with-va/4277675#4277675) should work for you, but `:contains` is a check to find the text *anywhere* within that element's text.  If you want a more robust solution, something like this would work:

```
$("#menu li > a").filter(function () { 
    return $(this).text() == theme; 
}).closest("ul");
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/zU7bU/1/** (based on @rahul's fiddle)

Comment: +1 - I would descend from `#menu`, but definitely the best approach here